# How can I load google amp url with react-native WKWebView?

Tags: react-native, wkwebview

If I pass the amp url to react native webView, it shows a page that asks to the user, whether to redirect to amp page or not.
I want to show the amp page on web view without redirection, but how can I do that?

This is the webview component I use.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

```
<WebView

                useWebkit
                startInLoadingState

                renderLoading={() => (
                  <View style={styles.spinnerContainer}>
                    <Spinner color={commonColor.lightBlue} />
                  </View>
                )}
                renderError={() => (
                  <NetworkError
                    refetch={() => {
                      WebViewRef && WebViewRef.reload();
                    }}
                  />
                )}
                allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
                source={{ uri: url }}
              />
```

so here source uri, if I put the amp page url such as 
`https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/www.traicy.com/20190127-ktrdia%3famp=1`
it shows a page that asks whether or not redirect to the amp page. If you click yes, it shows the amp page though.